# Cross domain request 405

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

```
POST https://Hidden.domain/saveLeadSearch 405 (Method Not Allowed) jquery.js:1
send jquery.js:1
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:1
saveSearch view:2026
(anonymous function) view:2005
confirmCallback bootbox.js:227
(anonymous function) bootbox.js:452
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:1
elemData.handle
```

I am making a call from different domain, and I don't have access to change the header configuration on host domain. How can I allow CORS?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. You need to change the headers on the host, otherwise how would the browser know it can trust you?

Comment: Since you dont have access to change the header configuration, you can't allow CORS. Also, since you're performing a POST, you can't use JSONP. Unfortunately, your only solution is janky hacks.